# What ObjectContext.SaveChanges() do under the hood?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is ObjectContext.SaveChanges() calls ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave | SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave) under the hood?

Just want to be sure so that I can use SaveChanges() to replace all SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave | SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does exactly that.

From ILSpy:

```
// System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
public int SaveChanges()
{
    return this.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave | SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks for introducing me to ILSpy.  I've been using the Reflector trial.  I prefer Reflector's UI, but *free* works out better for me :)

Comment: @adrift: The Resharper team has also produced a free decompiler called dotPeek. Last time I tried it, it seemed less responsive than ILSpy, but I imagine it will improve over time. http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/